# Call array from php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, typescript

If i want to call an array from php into typescript also in an array form how i can do it 
this is my php  code :

```
$AccessQuery = "SELECT name,lastname,phone,email
                      FROM user
                     INNER JOIN access ON id

                     WHERE id 
$userQuery = mysqli_query($localhost, $AccessQuery) or trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
while ($AccessQueryRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userQuery)) {
    $AccessData[] = array(
        'id' => $AccessQueryRow['id'],
        'code' => $AccessQueryRow['code'],

    );
};

$arr = array(

    "user_access_details" => $AccessData,

);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

I try this in order to encoded and use each one as a variable in an array

```
 var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
```

what i really want is how i can put each menu_id in an array field :
arr= {id1,id2}
the same for the code

Comment: eh, you have a syntax error and your query looks to be missing something

Comment: Please take the time to format your post correctly to make it easier or us to help you.

Comment: but my work work fine and give the result i need what i relay need is how i call this array " $AccessData[] " into my app in form of array in order to fetch all data into this array

Answer (score 1):

> how i can put each menu_id in an array field : arr= {id1,id2}

If you only care about the ids, ignore the `code` values.  Get the array of the shape you want in PHP.

```
while ($AccessQueryRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userQuery)) {
    $AccessData[] = $AccessQueryRow['id'];
};

echo json_encode($AccessData);
```

On the client side:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
```

The result will be the array of just ids.